# Git "merge" 2 origins

Tags: git

While moving a project between Git repositories I came into a situation when `git remote -v` gives me:

```
old-origin https://git.server1(fetch)
old-origin https://git.server1(push)
origin https://git.server2(fetch)
origin https://git.server2(push)
```

And `git branch -a` gives me only 1 branch under origin (remotes/origin/develop) and all other branches under old-origin (e.g. remotes/old-origin/master). I performed final push being on develop branch.

How can I "merge" 2 origins into one? So that all branches are under origin now.

Comment: @GoodDeeds Thanks! It should. Checking now.